# Diagonal Design and Skew Container in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-container, flutter-clippath

I want to achieve the layout as attached image in this question
there are 3 colors:
navy, purple, and white.
I'm aware that custom clipper can be used, but I'm unable to make one and what values to use
in it. A solution with explanation will be quite helpful

This is the outcome I'm trying to achieve

[image]

Comment: CustomPaint might be easier option

Comment: thats great @YeasinSheikh but then how can i add text widgets over it
like a large title text at top 
then a smaller text in the middle
and the smallest at bottom

it would be great if you can add code snippet with an image along with it for understanding

Comment: use `CustomPaint(...,child:Column(yourWidgets)`. call child parameter and use it the way you like

Comment: sorry link isnt working here. you may referring to the Stack widget.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using [`CustomPaint`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/CustomPaint-class.html) for this

```dart
class AppU extends StatelessWidget {
  const AppU({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: CustomPaint(
        painter: BodyPainter(),
        size: Size.infinite,
      ),
    );
  }
}

class BodyPainter extends CustomPainter {
  final bottomPadding = 48;
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    Path path = Path()
      ..lineTo(size.width, 0)
      ..lineTo(size.width, size.height * .65) //65& on left
      ..lineTo(0, size.height - bottomPadding)
      ..lineTo(0, 0);

    Paint paint = Paint()..color = Colors.blue;

    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
    // bottom line

    paint
      ..color = Colors.green
      ..strokeWidth = 20;
    canvas.drawLine(Offset(-20, size.height - bottomPadding),
        Offset(size.width + 20, size.height * .65), paint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) => false;
}
```

[image]

You can find more about [`ui-Path`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Path-class.html)

Comment: Quite an elegant solution!!
Thanks @Yeasin Sheikh
I've accepted the answer

Comment: glad to help, explore the link to get the concept.

Comment: yeah sure, will do